# What is the maximum number of Check Constraints a Column can have?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on SQL Server 2012

I would like to know what is the maximum number of Check Constraints a Column can have?

I tried searching online, but couldn't find

Comment: How many are you planning to create? Microsoft recommends no more than 253 foreign key constraints per column, though you are only limited by the number of objects in a database (2,147,483,647). I think the same goes for check constraints per table. You should be limited to one check constaint per column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say 1, since you only obtain a *column* check constraint by declaring it inline with the rest of the column definition, and you cannot declare multiple such constraints at that point.

```
create table T (ID int not null CHECK (ID > 10) CHECK (ID < 99))
```

Produces the result:

> Msg 8148, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>
> More than one column CHECK constraint specified for column 'ID', table 'T'.

However, you can declare as many *table* constraints as you like, up to the theoretical limit that [Patrick's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23334446/15498) mentions. But as with many things, if you have to *ask* about a limit, you're probably doing something wrong. I.e. around about the time that you're writing your 50th constraint about one column, shouldn't you be asking yourself why you have so many?

---

Okay, this answer obviously is causing some confusion. At the end of the day, there's not much to distinguish between column check constraints and table check constraints that just happen to only mention a single column. All I'd like to point out is that the *system* does seem to draw distinctions between them. Whether that actually achieves any efficiencies (e.g. column check constraints need not be considered if the column they apply to isn't mentioned in a query) I couldn't say for sure.

But SQL Server insists on there only being a maximum of a single *column* check constraint per column in the table, and exposes this information in it's catalogs. For example, in [`sys.check_constraints`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187388.aspx), it exposes the `parent_column_id` which is described as

> 0 indicates a table-level CHECK constraint.
>
> Non-zero value indicates that this is a column-level CHECK constraint defined on the column with the specified ID value.

Comment: Yes, if I give it your way, it throws the error. However, I just tried this: create table S (ID int not null CHECK (ID > 10), CHECK (ID < 99)) It works. You need to use a comma between the check constraints.

Comment: Yes, but that comma means that the second constraint is an unnamed *table* check constraint, not a *column* constraint.

Comment: No. I even tried giving a named check constraint. Like this:

create table A (ID int not null constraint ck3 CHECK (ID > 10), constraint ck4 CHECK (ID < 99))

Comment: But again, you're creating *table* constraints as the second constraint, rather then *column* constraints. That second constraint in your examples is a constraint that is attached to the *table*, not to the `ID` column. If your question was how many constraints a *column* can have, then the answer is `1`. If your question is how many *table* constraints can *mention* a particular column, then the answer is as many as you want.

Comment: Okay, but the second constraint still ensures whether my value is <90 (in this example). So, if I do: insert into S values (12), (11), (102), I get an error, as the value 102, gets checked against my second constraint. So should it not be a column constraint? How does it get categorized as a table constraint?

Comment: It gets characterized as a table constraint because it's introduced as a separate "entity" in the create table statement. After that comma, you could have gone on to declare another column, or any other type of table-level constraint such as PK or FK, as well as what you're doing by introducing a check constraint.

Comment: Oh. Okay. Alright. So, logically speaking, with that constraint after a comma, I would still be able to put multiple restrictions on my column, but it is categorized as table constraints. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are pretty good since the maximum number of objects, including constraints, database wide is [2,147,483,647](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). There doesn't seem to be a maximum number of check constraints on a column / table.

Technet:

> Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and constraints. The sum of the number of all objects in a database cannot exceed 2,147,483,647.